# 408 Request TimeOut on weblogic 12C

Tags: rest, maven-plugin, weblogic12c

We have a Maven project called Jira communicator which has the code to call jira rest api's, i have added the jira communicator(jar)as dependency to one of our web project. in our web project we are trying to call jira rest api through jira communicator classes but we are getting 408 Request TimeOut Error and its working fine out side of web project.

so we are thinking that the issue is with the weblogic server, and have tried by increasing the values of HTTP Duration,Tunneling client ping,timeout sec but non of them worked. Can anyone please help why am getting this error??

here is my code in Jira communicator.

```html
try {
   requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>("Headers", getHeaders());

   LOG.error("the Http header details of the request: " + requestEntity.getHeaders());
      
   String url = jiraurl + key;
      
   LOG.error("The JIRA URL to get the Jira details: " + url);
      
   response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class); //getting the 408 Request Timout here
      
  } catch (Exception e) {
   LOG.debug(e.getMessage());
  }
```

And the error at console is

```html
<10-Apr-2018, 11:37:34,538 AM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\SOFTDEV\TOOLS\oracle\WEBLOG~1.2\wlserver\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks.> 
<10-Apr-2018, 11:37:34,538 AM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\SOFTDEV\TOOLS\oracle\jdk8\jre\lib\security\cacerts.> 
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] 2018-04-10 11:37:54,664 [10.2.19.139-agr0036] DEBUG JiraConsumer::getJira - 408 Request Timeout
```

Comment: Can you confirm after how much time you get the Request Timeout ? Instead of just e.getMessage() try to print the whole stack, you may get more clue on what needs to be tuned

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into Complete Message Timeout, usually the time it takes to get the timeout gives a hint on which of the timeout thresholds was breached in the first place.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/channels/ConfigureDefaultNetworkConnections.html